# "Torchrun: command not found" in docker container on wsl2

Tags: docker, ubuntu, pytorch, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

This is my first time dealing with docker image. I am using wsl2 (Ubuntu-22.04).
(I'll give more details, because maybe I don't understand the principle of docker operation)

### Prerequisites:

1. Installed Nvidia drivers (on my Nvidia GEFORCE 1080), installed wsl2 (according to this guide from NVIDIA https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#getting-started-with-cuda-on-wsl), installed CUDA (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=WSL-Ubuntu&target_version=2.0&target_type=deb_local).
2. Installed Docker Desktop on Windows with WSL integration. Now I can run the docker command from wsl.
   **Next, I followed the instructions from the github of the project I want to use.**
3. Downloaded the image using docker pull.
   Next, according to the instructions, I have to run run.sh, which includes these lines:

```
IMAGE_NAME=yalm-cuda11-ds:1.0

docker run \
--mount type=bind,source=/dev/shm,target=/dev/shm \.
-v $HOME:$HOME.
--name "some-image-${USER}" \
-v ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}:${SSH_AUTH_SOCK} -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" \
-e REAL_USER="${USER}" \
--net host -it --rm
$IMAGE_NAME /bin/bash
```

After this command I got this output:

```
$ sudo bash run.sh
[sudo] password for maxet24:

=============
== PyTorch ==
=============

NVIDIA Release 20.11 (build 17345815)
PyTorch Version 1.8.0a0+17f8c32

Container image Copyright (c) 2020, NVIDIA CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.

Copyright (c) 2014-2020 Facebook Inc.
Copyright (c) 2011-2014 Idiap Research Institute (Ronan Collobert)
Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Deepmind Technologies    (Koray Kavukcuoglu)
Copyright (c) 2011-2012 NEC Laboratories America (Koray Kavukcuoglu)
Copyright (c) 2011-2013 NYU                      (Clement Farabet)
Copyright (c) 2006-2010 NEC Laboratories America (Ronan Collobert, Leon Bottou, Iain Melvin, Jason Weston)
Copyright (c) 2006      Idiap Research Institute (Samy Bengio)
Copyright (c) 2001-2004 Idiap Research Institute (Ronan Collobert, Samy Bengio, Johnny Mariethoz)
Copyright (c) 2015      Google Inc.
Copyright (c) 2015      Yangqing Jia
Copyright (c) 2013-2016 The Caffe contributors
All rights reserved.

NVIDIA Deep Learning Profiler (dlprof) Copyright (c) 2020, NVIDIA CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.

Various files include modifications (c) NVIDIA CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.
NVIDIA modifications are covered by the license terms that apply to the underlying project or file.

WARNING: The NVIDIA Driver was not detected.  GPU functionality will not be available.
   Use 'nvidia-docker run' to start this container; see
   https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/nvidia-docker .

NOTE: MOFED driver for multi-node communication was not detected.
      Multi-node communication performance may be reduced.

root@docker-desktop:/workspace#
```

### Problem:

Next, you need to run the file generate_interactive.sh, which has this content:

```
# Set visible devices
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7"

# Set MP_SIZE to the number of devices
MP_SIZE=8

# Provide path to vocab file and model
VOCAB_PATH="yalm100b_checkpoint/vocab/voc_100b.sp"
MODEL_PATH="yalm100b_checkpoint/weights"
LOAD_ARGS="\
    --vocab-file ${VOCAB_PATH} \
    --load ${MODEL_PATH}"

# Set generation parameters
GEN_ARGS="
    --temperature 1.0 \
    --top_p 0.9 \
    --seed 1234 \
    --seq-length 256 \
    --out-seq-length 128"

HPARAM_ARGS="\
    --pos-encoding-type rotary \
    --num-layers 80 \
    --embedding-size 2048 \
    --hidden-size 10240 \
    --intermediate-size 27308 \
    --activation-type geglu \
    --num-attention-heads 128 \
    --max-position-embeddings 1024 \
    --tokenizer-type SentencePiece \
    --fp16"

DISTRIBUTED_ARGS="--nproc_per_node $MP_SIZE \
                  --nnodes 1 \
                  --node_rank 0 \
                  --master_addr localhost \
                  --master_port=1234"

COMMON_ARGS="\
    --num-samples 0 \
    --load-release-checkpoint \
    --batch-size 1 \
    --model-parallel-size $MP_SIZE \
    --make-vocab-size-divisible-by 1"

torchrun $DISTRIBUTED_ARGS megatron_lm/tools/generate_samples_gpt2.py \
    $LOAD_ARGS \
    $HPARAM_ARGS \
    $COMMON_ARGS \
    $GEN_ARGS
```

But I get the error: generate_interactive.sh: line 47: torchrun: command not found

To make it clearer, here's a piece of the infstructure I used:
[image]

As you can see, here are the neural network weights that I downloaded before this. But next, I'm instructed to run the container on. But in this case I don't have access to the weights. And neither to the generate_interactive.sh file (so I just created it in the container myself, since it's just a set of commands).

### Questions:

1. Am I doing everything right? It's weird that I'm downloading the project files first, and then going into the isolated container.
2. If I'm doing everything right, what about the torchrun: command not found error? As you saw when running run.sh, PyTorch is installed. This is strange.

P.S.
I've reinstalled about 6 versions of Ubuntu on VirtualBox, sat for 9 hours with git bash on Windows 10 trying to run this, so I don't understand what to do anymore.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Running **torchrun** from a **.sh** file did not work. I just ran all the commands from there sequentially.